# Replace parent class event with my own

Tags: c#

I'd like to implement a new version of `TextBox`, let's call it `FunkyTextBox` that will raise `TextChanged` event only after every third text change.

If I only wanted to raise another event for this, let's call it `FunkyTextChanged`, the implementation is straightforward:

```
class FunkyTextBox : TextBox
{
    int counter = 0;
    int MAX_CHANGES = 3;
    public event EventHandler FunkyTextChanged;

    public FunkyTextBox()
    {
        this.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (++counter < MAX_CHANGES)
                return;
            counter = 0;
            if (FunkyTextChanged != null)
                FunkyTextChanged(this, null);
        };
    }
}
```

But this approach has one disadvantage - user would assume to use `TextChanged`, which is the parent's version that is raised after single change and wouldn't think to subscribe to `FunkyTextChanged` event.

Is it possible to use `TextChanged` event for this? To somehow hide parent's TextChnaged from users of `FunkyTextBox` and replace it with its own?

Comment: events in general, but Windows Forms in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for something like :

```
    class FunkyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int MAX_CHANGES = 3;

        public FunkyTextBox()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (++counter < MAX_CHANGES)
                return;
            counter = 0;
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The target is to not have `FunkyTextChanged` at all, but to let user subscribe to `TextChanged` and receive it after 3 changes

Answer (score 2):

Simply override the `OnTextChanged` protected method with your implementation.

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e){
  // your code here
}
```

As this method is virtual, if you use your custom textbox, this method should be called.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.ontextchanged.aspx) for WinForms and
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.ontextchanged.aspx) for WPF.